# Why does loop stop after two times when there are 873 rows?

Tags: excel, vba

Does anyone know why the following code only loops twice and stops, rather than running through all 873 rows. Note, Col D is the task Subject column and Col I is the task due date column:

'This project code creates tasks based on the Excel table in "Master Sheet" tab.

```
    Sub CreateTasks()

    Dim cell As Excel.Range
    Dim rng As Excel.Range
    Dim wholeColumn As Excel.Range
    Dim startingCell As Excel.Range
    Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim tsk As Outlook.TaskItem
    Dim wkbk As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wksht As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim arrData As Variant
    Dim i As Long

' Start Outlook
    Set oApp = GetOutlookApp
    If oApp Is Nothing Then
      MsgBox "Could not start Outlook.", vbInformation
      Exit Sub
    End If

' Read worksheet range into an array in one go
    Set wkbk = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wksht = wkbk.Worksheets("Master Sheet")
    Set wholeColumn = Worksheets("Master Sheet").Range("D:D")
    lastRow = wholeColumn.End(xlDown).Row - 2
    Set startingCell = Worksheets("Master Sheet").Range("D4")
    Set rng = Worksheets("Master Sheet").Range(startingCell, startingCell.Offset(lastRow, 5))
    arrData = Application.Transpose(rng.Value)

' loop through array and create tasks for each record
    For i = LBound(arrData, 2) To UBound(arrData, 2)
      Set tsk = oApp.CreateItem(olTaskItem)
      With tsk
        .Subject = arrData(1, i)
        .DueDate = arrData(6, i)
        .Save
      End With
    Next i

    End Sub

    Function GetOutlookApp() As Outlook.Application
' return Outlook.Application object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetOutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you will find that your lastRow variable is not what you think it should be. Change the calculation to:

```
Set wksht = wkbk.Worksheets("Master Sheet")
lastRow = wksht.Cells(wksht.rows.count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
Set startingCell = wksht.Range("D4")
Set rng = wksht.Range(startingCell, wksht.Cells(lastRow, 5))
arrData = Application.Transpose(rng.Value)
```

Comment: I second this. When you are in cell `D1` and hit `end-down`, where do you end up?

Comment: Matt, I go to R:10161.

Comment: Rory, when I run the code with your change, I get a debug at this line: et rng = Worksheets("Master Sheet").Range(startingCell, startingCell.Offset(lastRow, 5))

Comment: It appears as though perhaps you have a two dimensional array and you aren't looping through both dimensions. Maybe have a look [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/forums/questions/vba-in-excel-help-looping-through-a-two-dimensional-array/) for a start.

Comment: The error is "application-defined or object-defined error" Any ideas?

Comment: I've just revised my answer to include the full code - can you test and see if you still get the error?

Comment: Sorry, Rory, I typed it wrong. Now, however, I'm getting it to loop 4 times rather than 2. Any more ideas?

Comment: What is the last populated cell in column D?

Comment: The last populated cell is Col D is 873.

Comment: My guess is that you are looping through only the first row of five columns and you need a second loop to get all of the rows. Something like that.

Comment: What is the value of lastRow?

Comment: The value of D:873 is "ETM - Manufacturing Request Report" and the value of I:873 is "None" for due date. The last actual date is I:861 if that helps.

Comment: I mean what is the value of the lastRow variable when you run the code?

Comment: Sorry; I wondered why you asked that. I'm not a programmer at all. Well now it won't let me get past the first iteration. I'm now getting a Run-time error '9' - Subscript out of range.